# how run diff php files inside dockerfile?

Tags: linux, git, docker, dockerfile

i try to automate geting differencies at php files on container, but I receive exit code: 1 and kill process.

```
RUN diff ../../../composer/vendor/leroy-merlin-br/mongolid/src/Mongolid/ActiveRecord.php ../../../diff/ActiveRecord.php > ../../../diff/diff-ActiveRecord.diff
```

How can I fix is?

Comment: Try adding `> /dev/null 2>&1` to the end?

Comment: I tried now but, havent worked.

Comment: @evolutionxbox i did ` || true ` foreach diff in the end lines, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`diff` returns `1` if there are differences between the files, which will fail the `RUN` directive. You could explicitly return `0` for that line if you don't want to break docker's workflow:

```
RUN diff ../../../composer/vendor/leroy-merlin-br/mongolid/src/Mongolid/ActiveRecord.php ../../../diff/ActiveRecord.php > ../../../diff/diff-ActiveRecord.diff; exit 0
```

Comment: yes, i have read about this, we have other ways to do diff?